# Latex sectioning, mixing arabic and alphabetic

Tags: sectioning, hyperref

As the title suggests I want to start off with Arabic section counting and continue with alphabetic for the source codes. It should look somewhat like the following. [image: desired output]

Currently, I achieve this by renewing the section command as follows:

```
\renewcommand\thesection{\Alph{section}}
\setcounter{section}{0}
```

But this results in a problem with the hyperlinks. If I no click on `A Source Code: Gridworld Environment`, it navigates to the Introduction. Somehow the hyperlinks are messed up, and I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: I think you just want to use `\appendix`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: This is usually done by `\appendix\section{Source Code foo} foo \section{Source code bar} bar`.